# Interesting LEFT JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Well interesting to me at least...

Say I have two tables:

myLookUpTable:

```
lookupId  | Name
--------    -----
1           Red
2           Green
3           Blue
```

and InfoTable:

```
infoId  lookupId  Amount  ParentId
------  --------  ------  --------
1       1         2       332
2       3         14      332
```

How would I write a query that returns every row in `myLookUpTable` and includes associated information from InfoTable if it exists for a certain ParentId?

Example:

querying for parentId 221 would return The following for `Name` and `Amount`:

```
Name  Amount
----  ------
Red   
Green
Blue
```

and querying for parentId 332 would return The following for `Name` and `Amount`:

```
Name  Amount
----  ------
Red   2
Green 
Blue  14
```

I've tried about ten variations of left joins with no luck.  Below is my latest:

```
SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount
FROM   myLookUpTable as mlut
LEFT JOIN InfoTable as it
ON     mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId OR it.ParentId is null
where  it.ParentId = 332
```

This seems like a simple issue, am I just over looking something?

Comment: Since you're constraining it.ParentID to be 332, it can never be NULL, which is in your LEFT JOIN condition. Your LEFT JOIN is basically turning into a de facto INNER JOIN because you're forcing out all of the NULL results in your where clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount 
  FROM myLookUpTable as mlut 
  LEFT JOIN InfoTable as it 
    ON mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId 
   AND it.ParentId = 332
```

SQL Server 2005 Testing results below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myLookUpTable](
    [lookupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InfoTable](
    [infoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lookupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO myLookUpTable Values (1,'Red')
INSERT INTO myLookUpTable Values (2,'Green')
INSERT INTO myLookUpTable Values (3,'Blue')

INSERT INTO infoTable Values (1,1,2,332)
INSERT INTO infoTable Values (2,3,14,332)

SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount  
  FROM myLookUpTable as mlut  
  LEFT JOIN InfoTable as it  
    ON mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId  
   AND it.ParentId = 221

Red   NULL
Green NULL
Blue  NULL

SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount  
  FROM myLookUpTable as mlut  
  LEFT JOIN InfoTable as it  
    ON mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId  
   AND it.ParentId = 332

Red   2
Green NULL
Blue  14
```

Comment: Hmm, did you test this? It's not giving me the desired results.

Comment: Dave, I think he's asking for a refund on his consulting time.

Comment: This is not correct, since it doesn't produce a row for myLookupTable where there are no joining rows for InfoTable.

Comment: @RMorrisey - see results above.  Blue isn't in InfoTable but is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The `OR it.ParentId is null` part shouldn't be there.

Otherwise - looks good. If you have some particular issues with it, please describe them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
where  it.ParentId = 332
```

when you use this where condition, you are eliminating any rows that don't have a ParentId, such as rows from the table on the left where there are no joining rows on the right. Use:

```
where it.ParentId IS NULL or it.ParentId = 332
```

get rid of the IS NULL check from the join statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
where  it.ParentId = 332
```

you need to do

```
AND it.ParentId = 332
```

Also get rid of `OR it.ParentId is null`

See also here [MySQL - How to get NULL if equality does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462514/mysql-how-to-get-null-if-equality-does-not-exist/3462532#3462532)

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause for ParentID is undo-ing your efforts to LEFT JOIN all the null lookup values.
You can move that constraint into the LEFT JOIN criteria:

```
SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount
FROM   myLookUpTable as mlut
LEFT JOIN InfoTable as it
ON     mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId AND it.ParentId = 332
```

Answer (score 0):

The post from Dave Barker is the right answer BUT:
If you always need to return exact number of rows that matches the number of rows in myLookUpTable, and the (lookupid,ParentId) is not unique in the InfoTable you might want to use one of the following options:

```
-- sample contents - note that there are multiple amounts for lookupid, parentid (3,332)
INSERT INTO infoTable Values (1,1,2,332)
INSERT INTO infoTable Values (2,3,14,332)
INSERT INTO infoTable Values (3,3,24,332)
INSERT INTO infoTable Values (4,3,34,0)
INSERT INTO infoTable Values (5,3,44,332)

 -- option 1
    SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount  
    FROM myLookUpTable as mlut  
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT lookUpId, SUM(Amount) as Amount
            FROM InfoTable
            WHERE ParentId = 332
            GROUP BY lookupId
        ) as it  
        ON mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId  

    -- option 2
    SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount  
    FROM myLookUpTable as mlut  
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT lookUpId, ParentId, SUM(Amount) as Amount
            FROM InfoTable
            GROUP BY lookupId, ParentId 
        ) as it  
        ON mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId  
            AND it.ParentId = 332

    -- option 2 using CTE
    ;WITH it AS (
        SELECT lookUpId, ParentId, SUM(Amount) as Amount
        FROM InfoTable
        GROUP BY lookupId, ParentId 
    )
    SELECT mlut.Name, it.Amount  
    FROM myLookUpTable as mlut  
        LEFT JOIN it 
        ON mlut.lookupId = it.lookUpId  
        AND it.ParentId = 332

/*
Name       Amount
---------- -----------
Red        2
Green      NULL
Blue       82
*/
```